# Triggering event by clicking on the app if a local notification has been recieved but not clicked on

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

When I receive a local notification, everything works fine when I click on it. However if for example the user does not click on it, I want to trigger the same events compared to if they did. How would I achieve this. Im thinking there might be an if statement within the

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method to test if there is a notification active that has not been clicked on?

Comment: AFAIK nothing like this exists.  You should only be aware of when the user *does* click on it anyhow, as that would be the more informative of the two notifications.

Comment: hmm I see well is there a way to just simply trigger an event to occur at a specific time, instead of firing a local notification at that specific time?

Comment: Problem is that depending on how long you've been in the background, you might be killed off before you could even fire off such an event.

Answer (score -1):

Do everything with `localnotification` in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`. And then put other stuff in `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`